# What is the limit on Facebook open graph stories posted per day?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app on Facebook. I have created graph stories for my app. And I am able to post on wall using graph stories. But I just want to confirm, is there any limit on number of graph stories that we can post per day?

Answer (score 0):

Some information you can found here 
[Facebook Limits Auto-Sharing Via Open Graph Apps](http://www.mediapost.com/publications/article/184937/#axzz2ZUlErFTo)

Comment: HI Jin I have read you link but there is no specific information regarding per day limit for graph stories. Can you please elaborate it to me?

Comment: @user1567770 I think that you can be able find specific number. Because Facebook changing this behaviors all the time.

Comment: :ok. So there is no specific limit on open graph stories. Facebook changes it from app to app right ? Means anyhow there is limit on it.

Comment: @user1567770 Who knows, maybe if you have lucky and you contact directly Facebook, you will get some answers.